# Python Object Property Sharing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class that keeps track of several other classes. Each of these other classes all need to access the value of a particular variable, and any one of these other classes must also be able to modify this particular variable such that all other classes can see the changed variable.

I tried to accomplish this using properties. An example is as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self._b_obj = B(self)
        self._state = state

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state

    @state.setter
    def state(self,val):
        self._state = val

    @property
    def b_obj(self):
        return self._b_obj

    @b_obj.setter
    def b_obj(self,val):
        self._b_obj = val


class B:
    def __init__(self, a_obj):
        self.a_obj = a_obj

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self.a_obj.state

    @state.setter
    def state(self,val):
        self.a_obj.state = val
```

I want it to work as follows:

```
>>> objA = A(4)
>>> objB = objA.b_obj
>>> print objA.state
4
>>> print objB.state
4
>>> objA.state = 10
>>> print objA.state
10
>>> print objB.state
10
>>> objB.state = 1
>>> print objA.state
1
>>> print objB.state
1
```

Everything works as I want it to except for the last 3 commands. They give:

```
>>> objB.state = 1
>>> print objA.state
10
>>> print objB.state
1
```

Why do the last 3 commands return these values? How can I fix this so that they return the desired values?

Thanks

Comment: Way to ask a really well thought out, detailed, specific question with both expected and observed behavior on only your 2nd question to the site.  Very well done.  :)

Comment: Sidenote: If you're on Python27, your classes should be inheriting `object`. And yes, agreed with @g.d.d.c, very well written question.

Comment: To provide additional context to what aneroid posted. Here is documentation on New Style Classes for Python 2.7: https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/

Comment: Except I didn't realise that that was the _only reason_ his/her code was failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems all you needed to do is have your classes inherit from `object` :-) That gives you [new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle) and [all their benefits](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).

```
class A(object):
    ...  # rest is as per your code

class B(object):
    ...  # rest is as per your code

>>> objA = A(4)
>>> objB = objA.b_obj
>>> print objA.state
4
>>> print objB.state
4
>>> objA.state = 10
>>> print objA.state
10
>>> print objB.state
10
>>> objB.state = 1
>>> print objA.state
1
>>> print objB.state
1
```

The specific reasons for why this would work only with new-style classes, [from here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors):

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.
>
> For classes, the machinery is in `type.__getattribute__()` which transforms `B.x` into `B.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, B)`.
>
> (from "important points to remember")
>
> - `__getattribute__()` is only available with new style classes and objects
> - `object.__getattribute__()` and `type.__getattribute__()` make different calls to `__get__()`.

Comment: You can add the documentation link I posted in the OP comment for additional info, if you like to add a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for that, to quote the relevant section.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added some information about it would work only with new-style classes.